# Using Javascript from Angular which is extending String

Tags: angular, typescript

pretty new to both Angular and JavaScript, so not sure whether this is a trivial one but I'm not able to google this out.

I need to use a proprietary, legacy JS lib which is doing some very bespoke  XML based marshalling/unmarshalling/remoting. All of its value objects having methods `toXML` and `toObject`, and also it extends stock classes like `String` with these methods as well.

I'm trying to get it work from Angular - I imported the source JS files, and after eg.

```
declare var Discrete; 
declare var String;
```

I'm able to work with methods which are ending up calling eg.  `Discrete.toXML()` but not the ones which calls `String.toXML()` - it fails at runtime with `TypeError: String.toXML is not a function`.

Also tried

```
declare interface String {
    toXML() : any;
}
```

but it didn't help.

Any idea to get it work? Thanks!

Comment: When you say you can't get `String.toXML()` to work. What does that mean? Is it a TypeScript error or a run-time error? Please update the question for a copy of the error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `String` is the string type constructor, I guess you need to extend interface, like this:

```
interface String {
    toXML() : any;
}
```

Not sure, but it may be that you need to define it in `string.d.ts` file.
Also you can try like that:

```
declare global {
    interface String {
        toXML() : any;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, neither `declare interface` and `global` worked, now trying to figure out whether this `string.d.ts` thing helps.

Comment: @nestven I found how it is made in another library. Take a look [here](https://github.com/andrewplummer/Sugar/blob/14fe9f81fe406e67b89dded7c52c0e406553f901/sugar.d.ts#L1075)